# Export all key value pairs from grep output without a loop

Tags: shell, grep, export, tee

```
grep "=" someFile
```

Above is returning few set of key value pairs like below.

```
foo=bar
id_num=6
some_val=best
```

Instead of using loop, is there a way to export all variable from the grep output.

Tried something like below, but is not resulting in desired behaviour

```
grep "=" someFile | tee export
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, if you **trust** the input file (not generated dynamically by random users):

```
source <(grep "=" someFile)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this option @Gilles Quénot. I have just tried my usual source approach with `source <(grep "=" someFile)` which did the trick actually!

Comment: GG @vinWin, I add it to answer